# email validation in php

Tags: php, html, sql, email-validation

I'm trying to validate my username as an email address, however PHP isn't letting me do this! what's wrong here?

```
//This checks if all the fields are filled or not
if (!empty($_POST['username']) || 
!empty($_POST['password']) ||
!empty($_POST['repassword']) || 
!empty($_POST['user_firstname']) ||
!empty($_POST['user_lastname']) ){
header('Location: register.php?msg=You didn\'t complete all of the required fields');
}

if (filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
$errors[] = 'The email address you entered is not valid';
}
```

here is the form i used in register.php

```
<form action="createuser.php" method="post" name="registration_form" id="registration_form">
<label>Email</label>
<input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="50" maxlength="50" /><br />
```

Comment: Would it be enough to send an user some email with a first-time-password and not validate more than that?

Comment: I'm just trying to make sure the user has entered an email as a username!

Comment: What is the email you tried, or the non-email? FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL allows for local mail addresses that do not specify a global domain, e.g. "user@localhost" is a valid email.

Comment: If i type any string it accepts it as an email address. i want it to only accept email address's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typo?

```
header('Location: register.php?msg=You didn't complete all of the required fields');
                                           ^---unescaped embedded quote
```

Your empty logic is also faulty. You're checking if any fields are **NOT** empty (e.g. filled out) and then complaining that they're not filled out. remove the `!` to invert the logic.

```
if (empty(...) || empty(...) || etc...)
```

Comment: Thanks! That still doesn't fix the email problem though :)

Comment: how is php not letting you do this anyways? it's rejecting all email addresses?

Comment: @Marc B That's one way to say don't validate :D

Comment: filter_var returns the filtered data, e.g. it'll return a valid email address. you're strict testing against boolean false, but it's returning a string.

Comment: You have a very uncool XSS injection vulnerability: http://goawaymom.com/login/register.php?msg=%3Cb%3Ead%20things%20happen%3C/b%3E

Answer (score 2):

instead of this use regular expression for validating your email address

```
function check_email_address($email) {
  // First, we check that there's one @ symbol, 
  // and that the lengths are right.
  if (!preg_match("^[^@]{1,64}@[^@]{1,255}$", $email)) {
    // Email invalid because wrong number of characters 
    // in one section or wrong number of @ symbols.
    return false;
  }
  // Split it into sections to make life easier
  $email_array = explode("@", $email);
  $local_array = explode(".", $email_array[0]);
  for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($local_array); $i++) {
    if
(!preg_match("^(([A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-][A-Za-z0-9!#$%&
↪'*+/=?^_`{|}~\.-]{0,63})|(\"[^(\\|\")]{0,62}\"))$",
    $local_array[$i])) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  // Check if domain is IP. If not, 
  // it should be valid domain name
  if (!preg_match("^\[?[0-9\.]+\]?$", $email_array[1])) {
    $domain_array = explode(".", $email_array[1]);
    if (sizeof($domain_array) < 2) {
        return false; // Not enough parts to domain
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($domain_array); $i++) {
      if
(!preg_match("^(([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])|
↪([A-Za-z0-9]+))$",
$domain_array[$i])) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

and then check if it return true redirect it to location if not then simply throw an error

Answer (score 1):

You would not get to Validate the email because your if statement is wrong .. it is checking if any of the post is not empty.

Replace it with

```
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['repassword']) || empty($_POST['user_firstname']) || empty($_POST['user_lastname'])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, look at the syntax highlighting for why you're getting parse errors.

```
header('Location: register.php?msg=You didn't complete all of the required fields');
```

needs to become:

```
header('Location: register.php?msg=You didn\'t complete all of the required fields');
```

Comment: Oh oops, that's how it is right now!
still doesn't solve my problem though.

Answer (score 0):

How about you use javascript window.location? Sometimes header function is sensitive.And also put a submit button in your form since by **default fields are empty** when loaded.

```
if(isset($_POST['your_submit_button_name'])){

if (empty($_POST['username']) || 
empty($_POST['password']) ||
empty($_POST['repassword']) || 
empty($_POST['user_firstname']) ||
empty($_POST['user_lastname']) ){
?>
 <script>
 window.location = 'register.php?msg=You didn\'t complete all of the required fields';
 </script>
<?php
}

   if (filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
   $errors[] = 'The email address you entered is not valid';
   }
}
```

NOTE: I remove "!" before your empty function since youre trapping the fields that are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this solution:

```
$FormData = $_POST;
if(isset($FormData['button_name'])){
    $Errors = array();
    foreach ($$FormData as $key => $value) {
        if(empty($value)) $Errors[] = 'Some message';
        if($key = 'username'){
            if(filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL){
                $Errors[] = 'The email address you entered is not valid';
            } 
        }
    }
    if(empty($Errors)){
        // @todo Do some action 
    } else {
        header('Location: register.php?msg=You didn\'t complete all of the required fields');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function check_email($check) {
$expression = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})$/";
if (preg_match($expression, $check)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
} 
}
```

Now use this method as :

```
if(!check_email($_REQUEST['ContactEmail'])){
  $register_error .="Enter the correct email address!<br />";
  $reg_error=1; 
}
```